# ASP.NET MVC : SortBy list issue

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sorting

I'm trying to make a GET request that sorts the results by a `sortBy` criteria.

Unfortunately the `SortBy` method doesn't return a sorted list.

Here is the GET request.

```
[HttpGet]
public IHttpActionResult GetComupters(int? Id=null, string ModelName=null, string ManufacturerCompanyName=null,
                                      string CPU=null, int? RAM=null, int? Memory=null, int? ScreenSize=null,
                                      int? Price=null, int? MinPrice=null, int? MaxPrice=null, string sortBy=null)
{
    var searchModel = new ComputerSearchModel() 
        { 
            Id = Id,
            ModelName = ModelName,
            ManufacturerCompanyName = ManufacturerCompanyName,
            CPU = CPU,
            RAM = RAM,
            Memory = Memory,
            ScreenSize = ScreenSize,
            Price = Price,
            MaxPrice = MaxPrice,
            MinPrice = MinPrice
        };

    var computers = ComputerFilter(searchModel);

    ComputerSort(computers.ToList(),sortBy);

    return Ok(computers);
}
```

Here is the sorting function:

```
private List<Computer> ComputerSort(List<Computer> computers, string sortBy = null)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sortBy))
    {
        return computers;
    }

    switch (sortBy.ToLower())
    {
        case "price":
            computers = computers.OrderBy(computer => computer.Price).ToList();
            break;
    }

    return computers;
}
```

Here is the `Computer` model class - just in case:

```
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ModelName { get; set; }
    public string ManufacturerCompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CPU { get; set; }
    public int RAM { get; set; }
    public int Memory { get; set; }
    public int ScreenSize { get; set; }
    public int Price { get; set; }
```

Could someone please take a look of why the sortBy method doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code.

Comment: Sorry, could you post ComputerFilter too, pls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you don't do anything with the return value:

```
ComputerSort(computers.ToList(),sortBy);
```

Should be:

```
computers = ComputerSort(computers.ToList(),sortBy);
```